# Is the natural frequency of the damping system equal to the natural frequency of the forced oscillator? For example a bridge and people walking

Tags: energy, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, oscillators, applied-physics

When resonance occurs, there is a maximum transfer of energy from the driver to the forced oscillator. This means that the damping system should have the same frequency as the forced oscillation because then, the maximum transfer of energy will be from the driver to the damping system.

However, this also doesn't make sense because if the damping system was at the natural frequency of the forced oscillator, wouldn't it just cause the forced oscillator to resonate too?

My example of this is a bridge and people walking on it.

When the bridge is oscillating at a natural frequency, the people walking (are the driving frequency) have the same frequency as the bridge which causes it to resonate. If you put a damping system in place, then the damping system should be the same frequency as the natural frequency in which then when the people walking cause the bridge to resonate, the maximum energy is transferred to the damping system...
Please someone explain!

Comment: I don't know what *kind* of explanation you're looking for but math explains it all: http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/Oscillations4.htm

Comment: This seems to be a paradox, but you are right. The maximum response *is* when there is the maximum transfer of energy. The important point is that the maximum response is still smaller than if there was *no* damping.